# Update/change category of a post when it's been inactive for a certain number of days

Tags: categories, comments, wp-cron

From the discussion setting, I found that WordPress can turn off the comment automatically when you don't get any comments for a certain days. I am trying to write a function so that I can change the post category from `cat1` to `cat2` when the post does not get any new comments for two weeks. Is there anyone who knows hooks for that action?

Comment: Hi bigevent, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: Hi Kraftner, I did not start any coding yet. It would be good to know what the hook is for checking post inactivity for a certain period of time.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event
You can try using scheduled job to solve this.

In the hook, you would write a function that checks all posts from yesterday and see which posts have received no comments. Then you will move those posts to cat 2 from cat 1. I would come up with mock code if you can give me more context of

- how many posts you have
- Do you want the scheduled job to run once a day

This approach is simple to implement and will definitely work for small number of posts but if you post thousands of new posts everyday, then it would slow down your site while the scheduled job is running.